# An asymptotic expansion

Tags: asymptotics

The function $w(x)$ satisfies 
$$\frac{d^2w}{dx^2} + 2x\frac{dw}{dx} - 2\beta w = 0$$
with $$w(\infty)=0 \text{ and } 0<\beta < 1.$$
By writing $w(x)= exp(-x^2)f(x)$, obtain the first two terms of an asymptotic expansion for $w(x)$ as $x \to \infty $.

Comment: And what have you done so far?

Comment: I have differentiated $w(x)$ and plugged it back into the equation .... then found that $$2\beta f(x) + 2x \frac{df}{dx} + 2f(x) - \frac{d^2f}{dx^2}=0$$
Then I took the leading terms which I think are $2x \frac{df}{dx} + 2f(x) \sim 0$

I'm currently trying to solve this? not too sure if any of this is right though

Comment: I'm assuming what I done is incorrect because I get $$f(x) = \frac{c_1}{x}$$

Comment: I get the same differential equation on $f$ (at first glance), but I don't think it has a nice closed-form solution like the one you suggest.

Comment: surely it works because if I substitute my $f(x)$ into my approximation I get $$\frac{2C_1}{x} + 2x\frac{-c_1}{x^2} \sim 0  $$ $$\Rightarrow \frac{2C_1}{x} - \frac{2C_1}{x} =0 $$

Comment: @smith There is an approach that can be used to recover the entire asymptotic series.   If you repost and let me know, I am happy to help.

Comment: Thank you @Dr.MV I shall repost it now, this question has been bugging me for hours now

Comment: @Dr.MV http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1492551/asymptotic-expansion-from-3-leading-terms