# WKB Approximation of Legendre Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Looking at the legendre equation, I want to find the asymptotic behavior as x goes to infinity (leading order, $\nu$~O(1))
$$y''-\frac{2x}{1-x^2}y'+\frac{\nu(\nu+1)}{1-x^2}y=0$$
So I let $y=\exp(S)$ and I rearrange to get
$$S''+S'^2-x^2S'^2-x^2S''-2xS'+\nu(\nu+1)=0$$
I get lost from here.  Wikipedia introduces $S_0,S_i,...$.  They do not really explain where these come from.  I believe I want to look at the $x^2$ terms because they will be largest at x goes to infinity, but I do not see how I will get a solution.

Comment: The usual WKB method, or at least the version described in the Wikipedia article, is not really used to find the $x \to \infty$ behavior of the solution to a differential equation. As indicated in the "An example" section of the Wikipedia article that you mention, it approximates a solution to a differential equation when a parameter in the equation is  very small. So, for your equation it may be possible to give an approximation of $y$ when $v$ is very large. Perhaps you should seek an alternate method.

Comment: I failed to mention that $\nu ~O(1)$.  Does that make a difference

Comment: I have come across method of dominant balance.  Is that more appropriate?

Comment: the first thing what comes in my mind is , that one can neglect the ones in the denominators as $x$ gets big. this should simplify things. Indeed we get an Euler ODE which is standard to solve.

Comment: So looking at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerDifferentialEquation.html I see that this will result in Bessel Equations. So should the asymptotics at infinity be similar to those at infinity?

Comment: Or can I just use Frobenius's method?  I see that it is valid in [-1,1] but will it suffice at infinity?

Comment: Sometimes a version of the Frobenius method works at $\infty$, see [Dr. MV's answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1492816/5531).